# What's the programming language of this code snippet?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

I'm rather puzzled by this programming challenge - I don't know what language it's in (that's part of the fun, but I need some help). *I'm not looking for the answer to the challenge, which is to find a bug in the code, so don't spoil it for me.* I merely need to find what fine language it's in. The code challenge presupposes that there's a bug in just one line in the code, so we've got to accept everything that's on more than one line.

I've tried in vain to figure it out. I've looked at [rosettacode](http://www.rosettacode.org) and I can't find anything even remotely like this there. The closest it looks to is [Algol 60](http://www.masswerk.at/algol60/modified_report.htm), but it's not strictly Algol 60 as defined there. There are various issues. For one, comments start with `%` like in Erlang. The `define` is nowhere in Algol 60, neither is the odd `<unsigned number> #` syntax. Algol 60 also used an escape syntax for identifiers (they had a separate namespace, usually printed in bold) - that's nowhere to be seen either.

Looking at less popular things that I'm familiar with, it's not in IEC 61131-3, neither is it HAL/S.

```
begin

  % Speed of light in meters/second
  define c=2.99792458e8#;

  % Convert frequency in Hz to free-space wavelength in meters.
  real procedure wavelength(frequency);
    value frequency;
    real frequency;
    wavelength := c/frequency;

  real f, lambda;

  lambda := wavelength(f);
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was fortunate enough to work with two ranges of machines which used Algol 60 heavily.
Firstly the English Electric KDF9 which had several Algol 60 compilers conforming fairly closely to the language described in the Revised Algol 60 Report.
Then I moved to Burroughs Machines which eventually transmogrified into Unisys.
So the DEFINE statement is a feature of Unisys Extended Algol for text substitution. See page 3-90 of ALGOL Programming Reference Manual [1](https://public.support.unisys.com/aseries/docs/clearpath-mcp-17.0/pdf/86000098-515.pdf).
I think that having to know that, in this flavour of Algol, number constants having an exponent part need to prefix this by @ rather than E is unfairly obscure!!  See page 2-6 of [1](https://public.support.unisys.com/aseries/docs/clearpath-mcp-17.0/pdf/86000098-515.pdf).

Comment: Awesome. That's what I expected: some "extended" implementation-specific feature. It's one of those things that unless you know it, you're not very likely to find it. Sure, I could have looked for available manuals for every Algol-60 implementation mentioned anywhere, and possibly I'd have ran into that UNISYS one, so it wasn't an impossible challenge, but it was fairly obscure. I mentioned HAL/S: it was used on Space Shuttle avionics, and as far as obscure things go, there's at most 2000 people (dead or alive) who had hands-on involvement with it. Makes JOVIAL a popular thing :)

Comment: Here is a description of the invention of the DEFINE.  See section VI page 17.
[Stories about the B5000 and the people who were there] (http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/B5000-AlgolRWaychoff.html#17)

Answer (score 0):

The 8th week of [Circuit Cellar Code Challenge](http://circuitcellar.com/cc-weekly-code-challenge-winners/) is now closed. The authors of the challenge have messed up, and I'll take it up with them, BTW.

The language *was* Algol **60** as I've said. There is no such thing as "just" Algol, with Algol 68 being an entirely different beast! The error was with the "exponent", supposedly the correct one was `define c=2.99792458@8`.

Alas, that week's challenge was bogus since they've picked up some obscure implementation of Algol 60, and not the standard one, so I'm in a way pissed at them. There's no point at being so obscure in a code challenge that's supposed to be solveable by someone other than the author. I mean come on, if no one on a site with stackoverflow's exposure would have a pointer to whatever obscure variant of Algol 60 that snippet was in, then did they seriously think there will be any answers?

Heck, it wasn't even obvious to most people here that it *was* Algol 60, even though Algol 60 is sorta kinda a big thing in the history of computing. Backus-Naur Form comes straight from the [Revised Report on the Algorithmic Language Algol 60](http://www.masswerk.at/algol60/report.htm).

When looking for the answers I went as far as running [Whetstone Algol](http://sw.ccs.bcs.org/KDF9/walgol.htm) on an emulation of English Electric KDF9 from mid-1960s. It doesn't appear that the challenge code used that particular variant, even though I got it to compile after first getting it into standard Algol 60 form (no define, no comments, special dealing with the keywords).

Comment: You needed to know the exact syntax before you could find the free variable? I imagine your letter of complaint will brighten their day no end.

Comment: The free variable is not the problem. It wouldn't be even if it was a modern language like C or Pascal.

Comment: "a modern language like C or Pascal" Yeahhh.

Comment: Even in Ocaml it wouldn't be a problem, you'd be forced to use `float option ref` type :)

Answer (score -4):

The bug is

> that `f` is a free variable.

This leads me to believe it really is a made-up language, just to test you in the abstract, because this error can be detected without knowing any details of syntax. You've analysed the major candidates for what it might be, and it's not really like anything. This again makes sense if the point is not that this is a puzzle to improve your skills with the language, but to test you on generic programming skills.

My hint for you in solving the problem is to try translating this to a real programming language, in full. There will be one error you cannot eliminate.

My second hint for you is:

> what is the purpose of lambda abstraction?

Comment: The question specifically says "*I'm not looking for the answer to the challenge, which is to find a bug in the code*". And what's the purpose of the hidden text? That seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: @BryanOakley The purpose is to hide the answer and the second hint, for those who don't want to see. The conclusion is only supportable once you know the answer. So, what exactly is your complaint?

Comment: My complaint is that people come to this site specifically for answers. If they don't want to see the answers, they won't come here in the first place.

Comment: @BryanOakley And this is an answer. Once again, what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is, I don't see the point in hiding an answer on a site specifically designed to give answers. What problem does hiding part of the answer solve? Likely the only people who read an answer are actively looking for an answer. To hide what they are specifically looking for doesn't seem to make sense. Plus, as I explained earlier, this doesn't address the actual question being asked, which is not "how do I solve this challenge" but rather "what language is this?".

Comment: I don't want to get into an argument with you. No, I'm not blind. I see the statement where you say "maybe it's a made up language". "Maybe" isn't an answer, and the main point of your question is obviously the part about the challenge itself. I think the usefulness of your  answer is limited because you provide a lot of information that was explicitly not asked for, and the part that _does_ address the question is more of a guess than an answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm sorry, but what you like to see here? A survey of all known programming languages, and an analysis of the divergences between their syntax and that shown in the snippet? OP has covered the main candidates, and noted the syntactic innovations. All that is left is to show that there is no reason why this has to be any known programming language.

Comment: @RossPatterson OP Specifically asks not to be told the answer.

Comment: You didn't even bother to look at how far (or close) the original entry is from Algol 60. So, it turns out that as far as I can tell it **is** Algol 60, with one bad line, and an odd comment syntax. Your "hints" are completely bogus. `f` is not a free variable, it's just a variable whose value was not initialized. The `lambda` is not an abstraction, it's a variable named after a greek letter usually used for wavelength. Sigh. You deserve every downwote you got.

Comment: @KubaOber So, it's my fault that you don't know what lambda abstraction is or does (note I nowhere say that the variable in the code `lambda` is a lambda abstraction), and that you needed to figure out this was algol before you knew that a free variable prevents a programme from executing? Anyway, enjoy the success of a life lived with your enormous sense of superiority and entitlement as you struggle to locate basic errors in your code.

Comment: @Marcin, the point wasn't about the free variable. In many programming languages, such things prompt merely warnings and bring undefined behavior. So that's not the issue here. Back when Algol 60 was in widespread use, the code to implement such a warning would have likely been an opulent excess that nobody would pay for. The problem from my POV was that the "define" line is bogus, as it's not standard Algol 60 at all. The problem as intended by the authors was that the "define" line has a syntax error in the non-standard syntax floating point constant.

Comment: So, just to clarify: both the "define" construct is non-standard, and the syntax of the floating point constant is non-standard as well. The "challenge" was IMHO completely bogus.

Comment: BTW, I managed to get this running (after some massaging) on an emulation of an implementation from late 1960s. I'm happy to report that the free variable is of no consequence. You get a random number on the output, no big deal, it doesn't prevent the program from executing. It's pretty much the same as if you coded it up in C. Besides a compiler warning, it runs and the undefined behavior reduces to a random number on the output.

Comment: @KubaOber I seriously hope that you are never allowed to write any software of consequence if you think that undefined behaviour is not a bug.